# How to cancel a season pass in itunes

Tags: itunes, apple-id, accounts

I have moved overseas and need to change my apple ID country.  How can I cancel passes I still have open?

Answer (score 1):

Think twice before you do this.

All your purchases, music, movies, TV shows, etc, will disappear from your purchases.

I did that when moving from the UK to Australia. Now I'm trying to go back to the UK store and its also near impossible due to another subscription.